# Link for Registering Visual Studio 2012 Express for web

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am facing this strange issue, I cannot register my Visual studio 2012 Express for web. It says "Page not found":

[image]

I am using this link:[Registration Page](https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizard.aspx?wizid=C7497E1F-ADA8-4302-9B50-B01855369B2A)

I also tried to register the product by going to Help->Register Product->Register Online.
This Redirect to same 404 error page.

Any Help is appriciated. I want to register my product.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizard.aspx?wizid=2525f0ba-d85f-4730-bd75-e1299f83e666&lcid=1033

I'm using Firefox on Windows 7.

Comment: That is for Visual studio 2012 for desktop :-(

Comment: I want to develop ASP.net web applications, so I would need Visual Studio Express for WEB right?

Comment: No, no, you can also use the destop version for sure, you just need to include the web assemblies. There are alot of instructions around in the visual studio community :) 
I hope that answers you question

Comment: But I wasted so much time to download and install this visual studio 2012 for web. If anyone could have provided me the registration page link then It would have been very helpful.

Comment: did this conversation solved your issue about visual studio?

Comment: Which web assemblies I would have to include?

Comment: using System.Web; for sure, and I'm not sure whats the point of your question exaclty but you should be able to create a new project... than select Web Project or something like this and there your will have default loaded the assemblies your will need